# Alternatives to UIWebView for rich content?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

In my app, I am displaying 4 "tabs", each are local content through a UIWebView.  I create HTML markup from my simple data.  This is slow to load and I'm trying to speed it up.

I'm using UIWebView to accomplish these:
1. hyperlinks
2. some styling - font colors
3. HTML tables

Writing my own class to handle this is okay for (1.) hyperlinks - I can use a touch event to call a method.  And (2.) styling - I can use UILables to do basic formatting, no biggie here.

BUT what I really love about the UIWebViews is the (3.) HTML tables!  I find it troublesome to line up the UILabels in a way that mimics HTML Tables, for instance, one cell's height in a row changes the height of all cells.

I'm looking for another perspective or knowledge of an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the UIWebViews that were slow - it was another method that I completely overlooked.  UIWebView still proves to be the best solution for the needs I stated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a tab-bar and UITableViews?